# Is is possible to distribute java Desktop application which uses executables generated using C?

Tags: java, c, shell, shared-libraries, executable

I am developing a Java Desktop application which runs a shell script. This script is supposed to run an executable generated using C.The executable which my C code has generated is dependent on shared libraries.

I don't want to include the C code in the Application. Hence I won't be able to generate a new executable on client's PC when I wish to distribute it. As I have read, the object code as well as the executable are machine dependent and therefore I won't be able to run this executable (generated by compiling and linking on my machine) on my client's machine having different hardware configurations.

Right now I have included only the executable in JAR and I am able to run the shell script in Java (using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shell_script) in Java). As I have said earlier, this executable is dependent on shared libraries and when the software(executing the script) is run  on different PC,it reports an error saying that one of the shared libraries is missing.

I want a suggestion on how to run an executable which is compiled and linked on different machine and which is dependent on shared libraries in a desktop application(which needs to be distributed).

Please comment if I am going wrong anywhere or if you feel that I have misunderstood any concept.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like "C executables" don't exist.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime.exec ("foo")` calls foo and is agnostic to source of the program. It only looks for it's name, and, if I remember correctly, it has to be in the path or to be specified with a valid path. You can read the name/path from a config file or it might be given as a start parameter or, ... - so that it might be explorer.exe on Windows, safari on OpenBSD or firefox on linux, and the user could replace these with shell scripts and your Java program wouldn't take notice. But of course it has to be available at the target and accept the parameters you hand it, and do what it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compile your C code into a different executable for every supported
   OS and put them all into your JAR file.
2. Detect the current OS from your Java application and [extract the proper executable for that OS from your JAR file.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))
3. Run the extracted executable.